# Click on a tab bar item and execute a method in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitabbaritem

I have a method as below:

```
- (IBAction)GoToMyWebsite:(id)sender
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cc.BPS_WEB_ADDRESS]];
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I connect this method to a tab bar item?
So that when I click the specific tab bar item, this method will be executed.

Thanks

UPDATE

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item { NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the `viewDidLoad` / `viewWillAppear` method. Or, if you have set the delegate of your UITabBar, you can use the delegate method

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`.

Reference - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Please check the code under UPDATE, nothing happen when switching the tab bar, any idea for it? Thanks

Comment: `self.tabbarController.delegate = self;`